# How to programmatically change the Index of QComboBox using QStandardItemModel?

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, delegates, qstandarditemmodel

How to use the `QStandardItemModel::setData` function to set the current value for a `QComboBox`  that is found in a certain cell for example at index (0,0) that works as a **delegate** such that the `QStandardItemModel::setData` function calls the `ComboBoxItemDelegate::setModelData` function.

I know that `ComboBoxItemDelegate::setModelData` function is called when an item is selected from the `comboBox` but my problem is that `ComboBoxItemDelegate::setModelData` function is not called by calling the `comboBox::setData`.
 So I want to call `comboBox::setData` or (any other function that) programatically that will call `ComboBoxItemDelegate::setModelData`

**What I have tried:**

Here is the `setModelData` function that is called when an item from the `comboBox` is selected from the UI:

```
void ComboBoxItemDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (QComboBox* cb = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(editor)){
         qDebug()<<"hello, i have been called from the setModelData";
    }
    else
        QStyledItemDelegate::setModelData(editor, model, index);
}
```

But when I tried to set the data of the `comboBox` (that is found in index (0,0)) to "Item A" by the following:

```
ui->tableView->model()->setData ( ui->tableView->model()->index(0,0), "Item A, Qt::EditRole);
```

the `comboBox`'s value was set successfully, but the `ComboBoxItemDelegate::setModelData` function was not called, and this is my problem

Comment: setModelData establishes the value that the editor obtains for the delegate, and as I understand you do the inverse, that is, you want to be notified when the model is modified and notifies the editor, in that the function that is called is setEditorData

Comment: You can't, the model doesn't know views, and the current item is a view-specific property. You can use the same model with different views, which can all have their own selection/current item independently of each other.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld you can answer the question to accept it, and if possible to provide a suggestion about what i supposed to do